# При открытии URL картинка меняется на undefined

Tags: node.js, парсер

Надо спарсить картинку с сайта. Суть в том, что при открытии URL самой картинки просто отвечает пустой страницой с undefined. Стоит защита на парсинг картинок. Как эту защиту обойти и спарсить картинку?

Comment: Добавьте больше информации, по типу кода, который вы написали для этого.

Comment: Проверь хедеры в запросе на сайте при получении картинки и в запросе у себя при попытке спарсить